# Error in rviz displaying urdf model

Tags: ros, rviz, roslaunch, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to create a simple 4 wheel robot with a camera and I have written this code for the urdf model:

```
<robot name="labrob">
  <!-- Base link -->
  <link name="base_link">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
          <box size="1 0.5 0.25"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="yellow">
        <color rgba="0.8 0.8 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <!-- Front Right Wheel -->
  <link name="f_r_wheel">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.570795 0 0" />
      <geometry>
          <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.2" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0.05 0.05 0.05 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <joint name="joint_f_r_wheel" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="f_r_wheel"/>
    <origin xyz="0.25 -0.30 0" rpy="0 0 0" /> 
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </joint>  
  <!-- Back Right Wheel -->
  <link name="b_r_wheel">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.570795 0 0" />
      <geometry>
          <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.2" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <joint name="joint_b_r_wheel" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="b_r_wheel"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.25 -0.30 0" rpy="0 0 0" /> 
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </joint>  
  <!-- Front Left Wheel -->
  <link name="f_l_wheel">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.570795 0 0" />
      <geometry>
          <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.2" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <joint name="joint_f_l_wheel" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="f_l_wheel"/>
    <origin xyz="0.25 0.30 0" rpy="0 0 0" /> 
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
  <!-- Back Left Wheel -->
  <link name="b_l_wheel">
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.570795 0 0" />
      <geometry>
          <cylinder length="0.1" radius="0.2" />
      </geometry>
      <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
  </link>
  <joint name="joint_b_l_wheel" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="b_l_wheel"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.25 0.30 0" rpy="0 0 0" /> 
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
  </joint>


</robot>
```

As you can read I haven't put yet the camera or the trasmission blocks. I just have written the basic structure of the model with the joints. I have also written this .launch file:

```
<launch>
  <!-- urdf xml robot description loaded on the Parameter Server-->
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find labrob_description)/urdf/labrob.urdf" />
  <arg name="gui" default="true" />
  <arg name="rvizconfig" default="$(find labrob_description)/rviz/urdf.rviz" />


  <!--param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg model)" -->
  <param name="use_gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
 

  <!-- source that publishes the joint positions as a sensor_msgs/JointState -->
  <param name="use_gui" value="true"/>
  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
 
 
  <!-- publish all the frames to TF -->
  <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="rob_st_pub" >
  <param name="publish_frequency" value="50"/> <!-- Hz -->
  </node>


  <!-- robot visualization -->
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" args="-d $(arg rvizconfig)" type="rviz" required="true" />
</launch>
```

In this launch file I am trying to display my model in the rviz environment. Via the launch file I call a .rviz configuration file which is this one:

```
Panels:
  - Class: rviz/Displays
    Help Height: 78
    Name: Displays
    Property Tree Widget:
      Expanded:
        - /Global Options1
        - /Status1
        - /RobotModel1
        - /TF1
      Splitter Ratio: 0.5
    Tree Height: 557
  - Class: rviz/Selection
    Name: Selection
  - Class: rviz/Tool Properties
    Expanded:
      - /2D Pose Estimate1
      - /2D Nav Goal1
      - /Publish Point1
    Name: Tool Properties
    Splitter Ratio: 0.588679
  - Class: rviz/Views
    Expanded:
      - /Current View1
    Name: Views
    Splitter Ratio: 0.5
  - Class: rviz/Time
    Experimental: false
    Name: Time
    SyncMode: 0
    SyncSource: ""
Visualization Manager:
  Class: ""
  Displays:
    - Alpha: 0.5
      Cell Size: 1
      Class: rviz/Grid
      Color: 160; 160; 164
      Enabled: true
      Line Style:
        Line Width: 0.03
        Value: Lines
      Name: Grid
      Normal Cell Count: 0
      Offset:
        X: 0
        Y: 0
        Z: 0
      Plane: XY
      Plane Cell Count: 10
      Reference Frame: <Fixed Frame>
      Value: true
    - Alpha: 0.5
      Class: rviz/RobotModel
      Collision Enabled: false
      Enabled: true
      Links:
        All Links Enabled: true
        Expand Joint Details: false
        Expand Link Details: false
        Expand Tree: false
        Link Tree Style: Links in Alphabetic Order
        base_link:
          Alpha: 1
          Show Axes: false
          Show Trail: false
          Value: true
        right_leg:
          Alpha: 1
          Show Axes: false
          Show Trail: false
          Value: true
      Name: RobotModel
      Robot Description: robot_description
      TF Prefix: ""
      Update Interval: 0
      Value: true
      Visual Enabled: true
    - Class: rviz/TF
      Enabled: true
      Frame Timeout: 15
      Frames:
        All Enabled: true
        base_link:
          Value: true
        right_leg:
          Value: true
      Marker Scale: 0.5
      Name: TF
      Show Arrows: true
      Show Axes: true
      Show Names: true
      Tree:
        base_link:
          right_leg:
            {}
      Update Interval: 0
      Value: true
  Enabled: true
  Global Options:
    Background Color: 48; 48; 48
    Fixed Frame: base_link
    Frame Rate: 30
  Name: root
  Tools:
    - Class: rviz/Interact
      Hide Inactive Objects: true
    - Class: rviz/MoveCamera
    - Class: rviz/Select
    - Class: rviz/FocusCamera
    - Class: rviz/Measure
    - Class: rviz/SetInitialPose
      Topic: /initialpose
    - Class: rviz/SetGoal
      Topic: /move_base_simple/goal
    - Class: rviz/PublishPoint
      Single click: true
      Topic: /clicked_point
  Value: true
  Views:
    Current:
      Class: rviz/Orbit
      Distance: 4.48689
      Enable Stereo Rendering:
        Stereo Eye Separation: 0.06
        Stereo Focal Distance: 1
        Swap Stereo Eyes: false
        Value: false
      Focal Point:
        X: 0
        Y: 0
        Z: 0
      Name: Current View
      Near Clip Distance: 0.01
      Pitch: 0.695397
      Target Frame: <Fixed Frame>
      Value: Orbit (rviz)
      Yaw: 0.513582
    Saved: ~
Window Geometry:
  Displays:
    collapsed: false
  Height: 882
  Hide Left Dock: false
  Hide Right Dock: false
  QMainWindow State: 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
  Selection:
    collapsed: false
  Time:
    collapsed: false
  Tool Properties:
    collapsed: false
  Views:
    collapsed: false
  Width: 1216
  X: 17
  Y: 28
```

The result of the roslaunch of the launch file of this package is a urdf model entirely wrong. On the left side panel under "Displays" I see the following:

- Global Status (with a Warning) > Fixed Frame (with a Warning) -->
  No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [base_link] does not exist
- RobotModel (with Error) > Status:Error -->
  URDF (URDF parsed OK)
  b_l_wheel (with Error: No transform from [b_l_wheel] to [base_link])
  b_r_wheel (with Error: No transform from [b_r_wheel] to [base_link])
  base_link (Transform OK)
  f_l_wheel (with Error: No transform from [f_l_wheel] to [base_link])
  f_r_wheel (with Error: No transform from [f_r_wheel] to [base_link])

I can also see the "TF" Display without Errors and with a tick.

I checked another similar [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/9365/no-transform-from-anything-to-base_link/),
but it didn't help me. I also need to mention that I tried to use the display.launch from the urdf tutorials but the error still occurs.

Thank you for your time and your answers in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239437/error-in-rviz-displaying-urdf-model/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I exited roscore, closed the terminal (I didn't change anything during that) and reopened it and it worked and showed my model correctly... I don't know what went wrong...

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) with karma: 354 on 2016-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suab123](https://answers.ros.org/users/44652/suab123/) on 2019-11-07**:
yes you are right restarting solved my issue..thanks

**Comment by [sree](https://answers.ros.org/users/56825/sree/) on 2020-08-08**:
Sir I am facing with same issue .I have placed 8 sonar sensors around the turtlebot.its launching succesfully on gazebo but while launching on rviz it is showing error

[ERROR] [1596911402.861785142]: Failed to build tree: parent link [base_footprint] of joint [sonar_front_joint] not found.  This is not valid according to the URDF spec. Every link you refer to from a joint needs to be explicitly defined in the robot description. To fix this problem you can either remove this joint [sonar_front_joint] from your urdf file, or add "" to your urdf file.
[robot_state_publisher-2] process has died [pid 15687, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/robot_state_publisher/state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/lekhasree/.ros/log/28d6ed84-d9a5-11ea-9c76-37d291b527b9/robot_state_publisher-2.log].
log file: /home/lekhasree/.ros/log/28d6ed84-d9a5-11ea-9c76-37d291b527b9/robot_state_publisher-2*.log